# error al enviar formulario con la palabra <script>

Tags: php, html, formularios

Quiero hacer una base de datos de snippets de codigo, pero si el texto contiene el tag `<script>` en el input del formulario, este no se envia y da error, si escribo cualquier otra cosa, no hay problema. Como se puede enviar código por GET ?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Es que meter código como tal en una BD es muy peligroso. Puedes crear el contenido, poner un identificador para el tipo, lenguaje, etc y luego si hay que construir una estructura de `script` lo haces en tiempo de ejecución, dentro de un entorno seguro.

Comment: por ejemplo, si quiero guardar el código de un botón de MercadoPago en una tabla para usarlo mas tarde, hago un formulario y un campo input donde voy a pegar el código. ```<form action="form2.php"  method="get" enctype="text/plain">
<input name="x" id="x"  size="100"> 

<input type='submit'>
</form> ```  pero si el código comienza con el tag `<script>` si lo elimino, se guarda todo bien, pero si esta palabra esta, no se envia el formulario, no se si me explico.

Comment: Por GET mejor que no envies código por la propia limitacion de caracteres que tiene un URL (unos 2000), y podría truncarlo sin darte cuenta. Es lógico que no permita la etiquta `<script>` para evitar vulnerabilidades por XSS.

Comment: Como te venimos diciendo, es muy peligroso enviar/guardar/transportar/mostrar snippets de código tal cual. Si, como dices, es una BD que gestionará snippets de código, lo mejor es que diseñes un modelo de datos que te permita gestionar ese contenido sin riesgo. Por ejemplo, puedes crear identificadores con los cuales sepas si es un `form`, si es un `script`, etc, puedes incluso modelar elementos de más bajo nivel, por ejemplo un `input`, y con idientificador saber si es de tipo `text`, `file`, etc y así. Luego construyes el snippet en tiempo de ejecución, en entorno seguro.